# wkhtmltopdf compilation on Ubuntu

Tags: compilation, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to compile `wkhtmltopdf` from the latest source. I am on Ubuntu 12.10 x64 server edition.

I used the instructions from [here](http://blog.tcs.de/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-server/) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation).

For the `wkhtmltopdf-qt` compilation, as mentioned by the author, the new Git repo is at `gitorious.org/~antialize/qt/antializes-qt.git` on the `4.8.2` branch. So, that is what I used as well.

Everything went fine. The compilation of both (qt and wkhtmltopdf) completed successfully. But I was able to use wkhtmltopdf only as root (using sudo). When I ran it as any other user, I got the following error.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

I had done all the compilations as root, with the files inside the root user's home directory (/root). I guessed that the wkhtmltopdf program needs to read the `wkqt` directory, where the compiled qt resides (and the `libQtWebKit.so.4` file). This directory was inside the root user's home directory as well, thus preventing other users from running `wkhtmltopdf`.

So, I decided to start from scratch again. This time, I put all the source files (`wkhtmltopdf-qt` and `wkhtmltopdf`) in `/usr/wkhtmltopdf`. But during the compilation of qt, I get an error with the compiler trying to access `qmake` at the previous (old) location where qt source was present (`/root/wkhtmltopdf-qt`).

Error below:

```
ln -s libQtDeclarative.so.4.8.2 libQtDeclarative.so
ln -s libQtDeclarative.so.4.8.2 libQtDeclarative.so.4
ln -s libQtDeclarative.so.4.8.2 libQtDeclarative.so.4.8
rm -f ../../lib/libQtDeclarative.so.4.8.2
rm -f ../../lib/libQtDeclarative.so
rm -f ../../lib/libQtDeclarative.so.4
rm -f ../../lib/libQtDeclarative.so.4.8
mv -f libQtDeclarative.so.4.8.2 libQtDeclarative.so libQtDeclarative.so.4 libQtDeclarative.so.4.8 ../../lib/
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf-qt/src/declarative'
cd src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/ && make -f Makefile.WebKit 
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf-qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source'
/root/wkhtmltopdf-qt/bin/qmake -spec ../../../../mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o Makefile.WebKit WebKit.pro
make[1]: /root/wkhtmltopdf-qt/bin/qmake: Command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile.WebKit] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf-qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source'
make: *** [sub-webkit-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

I don't understand how this is possible when I am starting with absolutely fresh source code.

Is there some way in which I can completely remove (uninstall) the previously installed `wkhtmltopdf-qt` and `wkhtmltopdf`?

I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

Apparently, the source code was not as fresh as I thought.

I was cleaning the untracked and modified files in the Git working copy of the QT source directory. Running `git status` showed no modified files. But what I missed was that there were a lot of *git-ignored* folders and files, which still had the info about the previous compilation. These files and folders were not showing up in `git status`.

So, I temporarily moved the `.gitignore` file outside the repo and ran `git clean -fd`. That cleaned out all unnecessary files. Then I moved the `.gitignore` file back. For safety, I also ran `git checkout -- .` to get the latest versions of all the files from HEAD.

Compilation worked after that.